# Add muiltple values from function to each jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, foreach

I have the below which is in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/7YFHX/

```
            <ul></ul>

            <script>
            function test() {
                var myNum = [1,2,3,4,5],
                    myNumTxt = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
                return [myNum, myNumTxt];
            }

            var myTest = test(),
                myTestNum = myTest[0],
                myTestNumTxt = myTest[1];
            console.log(myTestNum);
            console.log(myTestNumTxt);


            $.each(myTest, function (index, value) {
                $("ul").append('<li title="' + value[1] + '">' + value[0] + '</li>');
            });
            </script>
```

What I want to return is a list item for each item in my array with the myNumTxt displayed in the title text as shown below.

```
            <ul>
            <li title="one">1</li>
            <li title="two">2</li>
            <li title="three">3</li>
            <li title="four">4</li>
            <li title="five">5</li>
            </ul>
```

currently I am returning the below.

```
            <ul>
            <li title="2">1</li>
            <li title="two">one</li>
            </ul>
```

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I return both values for each?

Comment: Hint: `$.each()` is looping over each item in `myTest`, and `myTest` has two items, each of which is an array. (For your given data structure you're better off with a plain `for` loop. But to hold that data, you're better off with a different structure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `for` loop like below:

```
var myTest = test();
for(var i = 0; i < myTest[0].length; i++){
    $("ul").append('<li title="' + myTest[1][i] + '">' + myTest[0][i] + '</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing myTest to function `each`. That is the problem. Try this:

```
$.each(myTestNum, function (index, value) {
    $("ul").append('<li title="' + myTestNumTxt[index] + '">' + value + '</li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it like this way,   


var listItems={};

var myNum = [1,2,3,4,5];
var myNumTxt = ['one','two','three','four','five'];

$.each(myNum, function(index,value){
    createHash(myNumTxt[index],myNum[index])
});


function createHash(key,value){
    listItems[key]=value;
}

$.each(listItems, function (key, value) {
    $("ul").append('<li title="' + key + '">' + value + '</li>');
});
```